# using variable i in data.table row index

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

I have question about using a data table in a for loop. Here is code and the error.

The warning message means I'm getting the wrong answer, only the first figure of 56184.97 is taken.
When I use the K index it works, when the i index it does not.

FOUND ANSWER: data.table doesn't like the variable 'i' in column 'i' in [i,j,by].

```
> len<-dim(dd)[1]
> for(i in 1:3) {
+   k<-i
+   cat("i is:", i,"\n")
+   cat("k is:", k,"\n")
+   cat(dd[i:len,savg],"\n")
+   cat(dd[k:len,savg],"\n")  
+ }
i is: 1 
k is: 1 
56184.97 53838.91 51527.4 49264.21 47063.1 44937.83 
56184.97 53838.91 51527.4 49264.21 47063.1 44937.83 
i is: 2 
k is: 2 
56184.97 53838.91 51527.4 49264.21 47063.1 44937.83 
53838.91 51527.4 49264.21 47063.1 44937.83 
i is: 3 
k is: 3 
56184.97 53838.91 51527.4 49264.21 47063.1 44937.83 
51527.4 49264.21 47063.1 44937.83 
Warning messages:
1: In i:len : numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used
2: In i:len : numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used
3: In i:len : numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, I'd suggest you give an example of your data table, but I get no warnings with the following sample data table, doing exactly what you're doing.

```
savg = c(1,2,3,4,5 ) 
y = c(2,3,3,1,1 ) 
z = c(4,3,2,1,1 )

dd<-data.table(savg,y,z)
len<-dim(dd)[1]

for(i in 1:3){
    cat(dd[i:len, savg], "\n")
}

#1 2 3 4 5
#2 3 4 5
#3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing local and global variables. This is a simple example that replicates your issue:

```
dt = data.table(a = 1:5)

a = 2
dt[a:5]
#   a
#1: 1
#2: 2
#3: 3
#4: 4
#5: 5
#Warning message:
#In a:5 : numerical expression has 5 elements: only the first used
```

What happened is that the `i-expression` is computed *within* the `data.table`, where `a=1:5` and not `2`, so the above expression is equivalent to:

```
dt[(1:5):5]
```

The solution is to be more careful with your variable names and be more aware of their scope. One way to be absolutely certain that `data.table` won't use column names is to give a single variable in the first argument, instead of an expression (this is mentioned in the FAQ):

```
a = 2:5
dt[a]
#   a
#1: 2
#2: 3
#3: 4
#4: 5
```